# Circuit current direction

Tags: electric-circuits

Can someone explain to me why the direction of the arrows are drawn the way they are in the electric circuit in the picture.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you analyze a circuit, you have to pick a convention for your potential and current flow. It doesn't matter whether you pick left-right or right-left, up-down or down-up, you just have to pick. After that, you do your calculations. If you drew the current "to the right" and you end up with a negative number, you know the (positive) current was really "to the left".

Look at the point $x_1$. There appears to be no current input - but current flows out, both into $R_1$ and $R_2$. That tells you that the choice was purely arbitrary. Although in this case it seems that they pick "down" for vertical resistors, "to the right" for horizontal resistors, and "up" for current sources. Convention? Because they felt like it? It doesn't matter.

Comment: Wow this cleared a lot of things up. Thank you for your answer! :)